# Using moment to round to next 1st or 3rd Monday

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

was wondering if someone could help, I am trying to use moment.js to take a date(like today) and then using it to return the next 1st or 3rd monday, whichever is sooner.

So for example today as 01/18, the next (1st or 3rd, in this case 3rd monday would be 1/20).

Or if today was 1/27 the next (1st monday in this case would be 2/03).

Comment: Could you add some examples of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited my question to include examples.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm is:

1. If the date isn't Monday already, move to the next Monday
2. If the day is the 7th or before, it's the first Monday
3. If the day is after the 7th and before the 14th, it's the second Monday so add 7 days to ge the 3rd Monday
4. If the day is after the 21st, move to the first Monday of next month

An implementation in without a library is:

```js
/* Get next 1st or 3rd Monday of month
** @param {Date} date : start date
** @returns {Date} date for 1st or 3rd Monday of month
*/
function getMonday(date) {
  // Copy date so don't affect original
  date = new Date(date);
  // If not Monday, move to next
  if (date.getDay() != 1) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 8 - (date.getDay() || 7))
  }
  let day = date.getDate(); 
  // If after 1st Monday, move to 3rd
  if (day > 7 && day < 14) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
  // If after 3rd Monday, move to 1st of next month    
  } else if (day > 21) {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
    date = getMonday(date);    
  }  
  return date;
}

// Test in March 2020
let d = new Date(2020,2,1);
let opts = {weekday:'short', day:'2-digit', month:'short'};

for (var i=0; i<31; i++) {
  console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-gb', opts) + ' -> '
  + getMonday(new Date(d)).toLocaleString('en-gb', opts));
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
```

An implementation using moment.js is below. It is tempting to use the `moment.endOf('week')`, but since it's "locale aware", it might end on a Saturday or Sunday depending on host system settings so the logic ends up being identical to the plain js solution, only using moment.js methods:

```js
/* @param {Moment} m - moment object for start date
** @returns {Moment} moment object for required Monday
*/
function getMondayMoment(m) {
  m = moment(m);
  // If not Monday, move to next
  if (m.day() != 1) {
    m.add(8 - (m.day() || 7), 'days');
  }
  let day = m.date();
  // If after 1st Monday, move to 3rd
  if (day > 7 && day < 14) {
    m.add(7, 'days');
  // If after 3rd Monday, move to 1st of next month
  } else if (day > 21) {
    m.set({month: m.get('month') + 1, date: 1});
    m = getMondayMoment(m);
  }
  return m;
}

// Test over March 2020
let m = moment('2020-03-01');
for (var i=0; i<31; i++) {
  console.log(
    m.format('ddd DD MMM') + ' -> ' +
    getMondayMoment(m).format('ddd DD MMM')
  );
  m.add(1, 'day');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```